# Can I edit XML loaded by xml.dom.minidom.parse?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, caching

As I saw, when we run

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
myXML = parse('anything.xml')
```

in a Python script, it loads the contents of "anything.xml", until you leave the script or <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> your Python session.

Is it possible to add attribute values to this loaded version of the XML in Python?

Comment: Your question is not clear. This is not caching, it is that the XML has been loaded. Are you wanting to just update that object, or are you wanting to modify `anything.xml`?

Comment: I don't want to modify original xml (anything.xml) I want to modify the parsed (loaded) XML.

Comment: That was very explaining Derek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `parse` method returns you an instance of `xml.dom.minidom.Document`, on which you can invoke the plethora of methods listed in the documentation of `xml.dom`. Here's a small example:

```
import xml.dom.minidom

d = xml.dom.minidom.parseString('<head>hello</head>')
d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].setAttribute('joe', '2')
print d.toxml()
```

This adds a `joe="2"` attribute to the `head` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><head joe="2">hello</head>
```

Comment: So, It does not modifies the XML file? Because I'm going to parse a file, not string?

Comment: @nightrider84: this example shows how to modify the *document* object created by parsing a file/string. You can then write this object back into the file or some other file. Consult the documentation for the write-side methods

Comment: One more question. [0].setAttribute What does [0] mean? Thank you

Comment: @nightrider84: `[0]` means the 0th (in programming it usually means "first") element of the list returned by `getElementsByTagName('head')`. You should probably walk through the Python tutorial first.